# Angular 4 - How to add logo in innerHTML?

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I have rendered the html response in my angular app. But i want to add the logo in this innerHTML in top right corner. How can i edit the content of innerHTML.

My HTML code is:

```
<div [innerHtml]="getReport()"></div>
```

Comment: How do you get the logo?

Comment: I will add the logo from assets... But how can i edit this innerHTML?

Comment: By editing the result of getReport()?

Answer (score 0):

```
getReport() {
    return "<img src='/assets/images/**YOURLOGOFILENAME**' />"
}
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)